# SQuirreL SQL Client: How to expand and select the table node on startup?

Tags: squirrel-sql

I have already asked the [same question for pgAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15012452/how-to-configure-pgadmin-iii-to-open-default-database-and-select-tables-node-on).

I would like SQuirreL SQL Client to either

- automatically expand the object tree to PUBLIC.TABLE
- or even better: restore selection/expansion state of last session

Bonus points:

- How to show the "Content" tab by default (not the "Info" tab)?
- How to use Windows L&F with plain instead of bold font?

[image]

Comment: Still interested in an answer? I'm working on an automated workaround.

Comment: 6 years later and nothing? Seems like a pretty simple thing to implement.